# preUpdate() siblings manage into tree: how to break ->persist() recursion?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Let's say I've got an entity like this

```
class FooEntity
{
  $id;
  
  //foreign key with FooEntity itself
  $parent_id;

  //if no parent level =1, if have a parent without parent itself = 2 and so on...
  $level;

  //sorting index is relative to level
  $sorting_index
}
```

Now I would like on `delete` and on `edit` to change level and `sorting_index` of this entity.

So I've decided to take advantage of `Doctrine2 EntityListeners` and I've done something similar to

```
class FooListener
{
  public function preUpdate(Foo $entity, LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $em = $args->getEntityManager();
        $this->handleEntityOrdering($entity, $em);
    }
    
    public function preRemove(Foo $entity, LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $level = $entity->getLevel();
        $cur_sorting_index = $entity->getSortingIndex();
        $em = $args->getEntityManager();
        $this->handleSiblingOrdering($level, $cur_sorting_index, $em);
    }

    private function handleEntityOrdering($entity, $em)
    {
        error_log('entity to_update_category stop flag: '.$entity->getStopEventPropagationStatus());
        error_log('entity splobj: '.spl_object_hash($entity));
        //code to calculate new sorting_index and level for this entity (omitted)
        $this->handleSiblingOrdering($old_level, $old_sorting_index, $em);
        }
    }
    
    private function handleSiblingOrdering($level, $cur_sorting_index, $em)
    {   
        $to_update_foos = //retrieve from db all siblings that needs an update
        //some code to update sibling ordering (omitted)
        foreach ($to_update_foos as $to_update_foo)
        {
            $em->persist($to_update_foo);
        }
        $em->flush();
    }
}
```

The problem here is pretty clear: if I persist a `Foo` entity, `preUpdate()` (into `handleSiblingOrdering` function) trigger is raised and this cause an infinite loop.

My first idea was to insert a special variable inside my entity to prevent this loop: when I started a sibling update, that variable is setted and before executing the update code is checked. This works like a charm for `preRemove()` but not for `preUpdate()`.
If you notice I'm logging `spl_obj_hash` to understand this behaviour. With a big surprise I can see that obj passed to `preUpdate()` after a `preRemove()` is the same (so setting a "status flag" is a fine) but the object passed to `preUpdate()` after a `preUpdate()` isn't the same.

So ...

#### First question

Someone could point me in the right direction to manage this situation?

#### Second question

Why doctrine needs to generate different objects if two *similar* events are raised?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've founded a workaround

Best approach to this problem seem to create a custom `EventSubscriber` with a custom `Event` dispatched programmatically into controller update action.
That way I can "break" the loop and having a working code.

Just to make this answer complete I will report some snippet of code just to clarify che concept

#### Create custom events for your bundle

```
//src/path/to/your/bundle/YourBundleNameEvents.php 
final class YourBundleNameEvents
{
    const FOO_EVENT_UPDATE = 'bundle_name.foo.update';
}
```

this is a special class that will not do anything but provide some custom events for our bundle

#### Create a custom event for foo update

```
//src/path/to/your/bundle/Event/FooUpdateEvent
class FooUpdateEvent
{
  //this is the class that will be dispatched so add properties useful for your own logic. In my example two properties could be $level and $sorting_index. This values are setted BEFORE dispatch the event
}
```

#### Create a custom event subscriber

```
//src/path/to/your/bundle/EventListener/FooSubscriber
class FooSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(YourBundleNameEvents::FooUpdate => 'handleSiblingsOrdering');
    }

    public function handleSiblingsOrdering(FooUpdateEvent $event)
    {
        //I can retrieve there, from $event, all data I setted into event itself. Now I can run all my own logic code to re-order siblings
    }
}
```

#### Register your Subscriber as a service

```
//app/config/config.yml

services:
your_bundlename.foo_listener:
        class: Your\Bundle\Name\EventListener\FooListener
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_subscriber }
```

#### Create and dispatch events into controller

```
//src/path/to/your/bundle/Controller/FooController
class FooController extends Controller
{
    public function updateAction()
    {
        //some code here
        $dispatcher = $this->get('event_dispatcher');
        $foo_event = new FooEvent();
        $foo_event->setLevel($level); //just an example
        $foo_event->setOrderingIndex($ordering_index); //just an examle
        
        $dispatcher->dispatch(YourBundleNameEvents::FooUpdate, $foo_event);
    }
}
```

---

## Alternative solution

Of course above solution is the best one but, if you have a property mapped into db that could be used as a flag, you could access it directly from `LifecycleEventArgs` of `preUpdate()` event by calling

```
$event->getNewValue('flag_name'); //$event is an object of LifecycleEventArgs type
```

By using that flag we could check for changes and stop the propagation

Answer (score 1):

You are doing wrong approach by calling $em->flush() inside preUpdate, I even can say restricted by Doctrine action: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/events.html#reference-events-implementing-listeners

**9.6.6. preUpdate**

> PreUpdate is the most restrictive to use event, since it is called
>   right before an update statement is called for an entity inside the
>   EntityManager#flush() method.
>
> Changes to associations of the updated entity are never allowed in
>   this event, since Doctrine cannot guarantee to correctly handle
>   referential integrity at this point of the flush operation.

Comment: This isn't an answer; should be a comment. BTW I've found another solution (that I will post asap) and you give me some pointers with that page: I will try to continue with preUpdate() to test if my idea is still a valid one. I would also like to underline that I've not changed any association between entities, so even if this will not be the optimal approach, I'm nearly sure that is still a valid one.

Comment: I belive it was answer at least to your question >>Someone could point me in the right direction to manage this situation? if it was not enough then sorry

Comment: yes, good solution, actually I have something similar just with a service that I need to call in the controller to reorder my entities that implements TreePosition interface. But this is same case as with a dispatcher that we need additionally initiate the ordering process, instead of full automatic call via preUpdate, that will be fired in every update action from any controller and add more graceful solution. So I was not able to give you full solution in my answer:) just passed  what I already had faced before, happy coding!